# Batch Script to loop through all files in specific Folder and TFTP to a host

Tags: windows, batch

I have a folder Data in ( C:/Uses/Public/Data ). It contains 100 of files and I need to iterate over all files in this directory and tftp to host. My tftp command for single file works

```
TFTP -i PUT <filename> 182.168.0.1
```

However, I am not sure how to embed this in a batch script that iterates over all files and use the above command to put to a host ?

Comment: The `xargs` command on Unix was made for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **[`For`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)** loop to list your files and pass each file as a parameter in your command:

```
@echo off 

For %%i in ("C:/Uses/Public/Data/*")do TFTP -i PUT "%%~i" 182.168.0.1
```

- In this **[`For`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)** loop you can inform the `Drive:/Path/To/Folder`, and that is to list all files `*.*` using `*`, and it will return the full path of each file in `%%i`.